# Anomalous bar on UIViewController in Storyboard. What is it?

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

I don't know where this bar (indicated by red arrow) came from. It's not listed in the Document Outline, and I can't get rid of it. Tried quitting and restarting Xcode, and it's still there. Anybody got a guess?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because it is a UITabBarController with no attached view controllers.

Comment: Hmmm...well, I have no idea how a UITabBarController got there. Any recommendations on how to get rid of it? Do I have to dump the VC and wire up a new one?

Comment: Yup, just click it and hit delete. Drag a new UIViewController onto the storyboard and then when you wire it up to a new file, make sure the file is a subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: Done. I guess I'll have to chalk its mysterious appearance up to one of those "things that go bump in the night." Thank you sir!